# Sticky/fixed navbar jumping when scrolled down

Tags: header, navbar, fixed, sticky

I think I found the actual reason and how to fix it, but am not proficient enough at coding to adapt the fix to my current code implementation. [Here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842304/scrolling-sticky-header-jumping) to the post with the fix.

My code is as follows:

```js
<script>
     var  mn = $("#MenuScroll");
          mns = "main-nav-scrolled";
          hdr = $('header').height();

     $(window).scroll(function() {
        if( $(this).scrollBtr() > hdr && $(window).width() > 780) {
          mn.addClass(mns);
        } else {
          mn.removeClass(mns);
        }
      });
</script>
```

```css
#MenuScroll {
    -webkit-transition: all 0s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0s ease;
    transition: all 0s ease;
}
.main-nav-scrolled {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
   bottom: inherit;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-bar" role="navigation" id="MenuScroll">
  <div class="wrapper">
    {% include 'site-nav' %}
  </div>
</nav>
```

Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks